# Why is my navigation stack mixed up after unwind segue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, navigation, unwind-segue

I have a navigation route that looks like this:

[image]

`A` is a `UITableViewController` embedded in a tab bar controller.
Tapping one of the rows segues to `B` which is a view controller embedded in a navigation controller. Tapping the pink button on `B` pushes view controller `C`, and taping "Recent Songs" segues to `D`. Finally, tapping a song on `D` runs the method `uploadSong()`

```
-(void) uploadSong {
    ViewControllerB *viewControllerB = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewControllerB"];
    ViewControllerA *viewControllerA = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewControllerA"];

    NSArray *vcArray = @[self,viewControllerA,viewControllerB];
    [self.navigationController setViewControllers:vcArray animated:YES];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"unwindToViewControllerB" sender:self];
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"unwindToViewControllerB"]){

        ViewControllerB *viewControllerB = segue.destinationViewController;
        viewControllerB.object = self.friendObject;
        viewControllerB.spotifyDismiss = YES;
        viewControllerB.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
    }
}
```

All goes well, and I end up back at `B` with the navigation controller's back button taking me back to `A` as I wanted. However, I find that if I instead tap on the tab bar item (bottom left) it shows me `D` again instead of doing what is common in apps and taking you to the first view controller in the stack, which in this case would be `A`.

So my question is, why after my unwind segue does my back button from `B` take me to `A`, but tapping the tab bar item takes me to `D` instead of `A`?

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that the fix was simply putting the view controllers in `vcArray` in the obvious correct order `[viewControllerA, viewControllerB, self]` instead of `[self, viewControllerA, viewControllerB]`. Now my navigation stack acts exactly as it should whether I tap the back button or the tab bar item.